# SQL query to ADD new column in table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I want to add the new column with the condition that if the value of 1st columns is diff. then 2nd columns then only it will be alter with condition OR else the value remain same.

[image]

The Above image will clarify my requirement more effectively.

Below query only alter the column but please guide how to apply condition in the same.

```
ALTER TABLE Wealth_CFY ADD Type3 AS (Type1 + ' ' + Type2)
```

Comment: Mysql <> Sql Server, which one are you using ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் Sql Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` statement to check if the values are same before concatenating.

```
ALTER TABLE Wealth_CFY
  ADD Type3 AS (CASE WHEN COALESCE(Type1, '') <> COALESCE(Type2, '') THEN Type1 + ' ' + Type2 ELSE Type1 END) PERSISTED
```

`COALESCE` is used to handle `NULL` values. If both `Type1` and `Type2` does not accept `NULL` value then remove the `COALESCE` function

Answer (score 1):

```
 ALTER TABLE Wealth_CFY
  ADD Type3 AS (CASE WHEN COALESCE(Type1, '') <> COALESCE(Type2, '') THEN 
   Type1 + ' ' + Type2 ELSE Type1 END) PERSISTED
```